# Does 18650 cell voltage sag have a direct relationship with its internal resistance?

Tags: power-electronics, batteries

When a cell is connected to full load does it drop some of its voltage due to internal resistance and quickly jumps back to normal whenever the load is taken off??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the basic effect of the ESR (equivalent series resistance) and the capacitance of the cell.

If you use any free circuit simulator and play around with reasonable values of R and C, you will get a better understanding of what's going on inside the cell. If you measure the given voltage drop with a known current and the time taken to recover, you can derive the correct values of Rs, Rp and Cp in the example below.

[image]